# Multi query for a join using hibernate criteriabuilder

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-criteria

I would like perform a join query using hibernate criteria API and map some of the joined fields explicitly. 
This is pretty straightforward, so my code resulted in :

```
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Country> criteria = builder.createQuery(Country.class);
        Root<Country> root = criteria.from(Country.class);
        Join<Country, Translation> join = root.join("translatedName");
        criteria.multiselect(root, join.get("fr"));
        TypedQuery<Country> tq = session.createQuery(criteria);
        List<Country> countries = tq.getResultList();
```

Country Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "countries")
public class Country {

    @Id
    @Column
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "name_id")
    private Translation translatedName;

    @Transient
    private String name;

    public Country(Country c, String name) {
        this.id = c.id;
        this.name = name;
    }

//getters...
}
```

Translation Entity

```
package database.models;

import service.model.Country;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "translations")
public class Translation {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String fr;
    private String en;
// getters/setters
}
```

This does exactly what I want. Multiselect statement pass to my constructor the joined field, and I store it in the right variable.

However, I encountered the infamous N+1 select problem :

```
Hibernate: select country0_.id as col_0_0_, translatio1_.id as col_1_0_, translatio1_.fr as col_2_0_ from countries country0_ inner join translations translatio1_ on country0_.name_id=translatio1_.id
Hibernate: select country0_.id as id1_0_0_, country0_.name_id as name_id2_0_0_ from countries country0_ where country0_.id=?
...
```

After some research, I have found that using the fetch statement instead of join solves this issue. Updated code :

```
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Country> criteria = builder.createQuery(Country.class);
        Root<Country> root = criteria.from(Country.class);
        Join<Country, Translation> join = (Join)root.fetch("translatedName");
        criteria.multiselect(root, join.get("fr"));
        TypedQuery<Country> tq = session.createQuery(criteria);
        List<Country> countries = tq.getResultList();
```

The query fails with the following (well-known) QueryException :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=generatedAlias1,role=service.model.Country.translatedName,tableName=translations,tableAlias=translatio1_,origin=countries country0_,columns={country0_.name_id ,className=database.models.Translation}}]
```

I've come to understand that DTO Projection that I use for mapping my custom field, and the join fetch are not compatible.

For the record, I don't even need my `translatedName` relationship to be fetched. I just want to extract the right language and map it in my entity.

Thanks in advance. Any advice ?

The main purpose here is having a field `name` from my country filled with the translation, and return it directly to the user instead of having a nested field with all the translation available.
For example, if I receive a query with lang=fr, I want to return :

```
{
  "name": "fr_name"
}
```

And not

```
{
  "name": {
    "fr": "fr_name",
    "en": "en_name"
  }
}
```

And I dont want having to iterate through my result set to map it manually for performance reason

Comment: You could also simply use `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`. Then you can go for `criteria.select(root);` and you should already get the full translation with that query

Comment: @XtremeBaumer This is not what I want. I need to explicitly pass the lang parameter to fill the translation with the appropriate translated value. However, it does solve the n+1 select query but still throws the QueryException if I try to add the joined language  to the select statement

Comment: You don't need to select the language parameter explicitly. Let Hibernate fetch the whole `Translation` and work with that

Comment: @XtremeBaumer The reason I need to do this mapping from the sql query is that I want to avoid iterating through my list of entities to map the translation manually

Comment: Hibernate creates a query which maps it automatically. In the end you have a full fetched `Country` with the the corresponding `Translation`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer As I said, I dont need every field of the translation table. I just need one, the language I want to return to the user. Maybe what I try to do is not supported

Comment: It is easyily done with a HQL query. Not sure how to do it with criteria though. Yet it doesn't matter if you fetch the whole table or just 1 field. In the end you have access to that one field. Right now you are just making it harder than necessary for yourself

Comment: Yeah I'm aware this can be done easily with a HQL query, but I need to apply dynamic filters afterwards, so criteria it is. I think my life will be difficult for the moment.

Thanks for your time ! :)

Comment: HQL allows dynamic filters as well, though it might be a bit harder to implement. So far I don't see any reason, why you would want to do it the way you describe

Comment: For the only purpose of having a field "name" from my country filled with the translation, and return it directly to the user instead of having a nested field with all the translation available.
For example, if I receive a query with lang=fr, I want to return :
```
{
"name": "name_translated_in_french"
}
```
And not 
```
{
"name": {
"fr": "fr_name",
}
}
```

And I dont want having to iterate through my result set to map it manually for performance reason

Comment: So 1 translation has multiple languages? Maybe you could post the `Translation` entity as well

Comment: Edited with aboved comment + translation entity

Answer (score 0):

The given code worked for me:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Order> query = cb.createQuery(Order.class);

Root<Order> orderRoot = query.from(Order.class);
Join<Order, Address> addressJoin = orderRoot.join("address", JoinType.LEFT);
addressJoin.on(cb.equal(addressJoin.get("country"), "France")); //some additional conditions
orderRoot.fetch("address", JoinType.LEFT);
query.select(cb.construct(Order.class, order.id, ..., join.get("fr")));
List<Order> orders = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

But for its execution it is necessary to have the Address address field; in Order with Hibernate relations and also in Order there must be a constructor with all fields from the select

This error:

```
by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=generatedAlias1,role=service.model.Country.translatedName,tableName=translations,tableAlias=translatio1_,origin=countries country0_,columns={country0_.name_id ,className=database.models.Translation}}]
```

can occur in Hibernate when you use a select join to host entities in a query, but do not include the query entity that contains the relationship.

For example, if we have an Order and Address entity associated with a @ManyToOne membership, and we want to use a fetch join to place the addresses when executing a query to fetch orders, then we can write the following code:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Order> query = cb.createQuery(Order.class);

Root<Order> orderRoot = query.from(Order.class);
Join<Order, Address> addressJoin = orderRoot.join("address", JoinType.LEFT);
orderRoot.fetch("address", JoinType.LEFT);

List<Order> orders = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

However, if we do not include the Order entity in the select list, we will get the error "query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list".

To fix this error, we need to include the Order entity in the query's select list. For example, we can change our code like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);

Root<Order> orderRoot = query.from(Order.class);
Join<Order, Address> addressJoin = orderRoot.join("address", JoinType.LEFT);
orderRoot.fetch("address", JoinType.LEFT);

query.select(cb.array(orderRoot, addressJoin));

List<Object[]> resultList = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

In this code, we select both Order and Address in the same request using the select method and the cb.array() method, which creates an array of objects containing the selected objects. But I'm still not sure how to implement the replacement